# Convert Twitter Time into a Pig DateTime object

Tags: datetime, casting, apache-pig

I am working on twitter data and have a field: `user_created_at` that looks like `Thu Jun 11 16:41:35 +0000 2015`.

I am not sure what the type of the field is since I got the fields using elephant bird. To covert it into `datetime` type, I did:

`ToDate(user_created_at, 'yyyy.MM.dd') as user_created_at`

but it failed with an error:

`ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name: POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate2ARGS)[datetime] - scope-148 Operator Key: scope-148) children: null at []]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Thu Jun 11 16:41:35 +0000 2015"`.

What is wrong? I am using Pig version 0.15. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match datetime format with input datetime string. Something like this.

```
ToDate(user_created_at, 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy')
```

Comment: And if it is impossible to find a matching format (like when you would have a CEST timezone) then use substring or replace to get to an acceptable format and put that into ToDate.